# Modifying struct pointers inside functions

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm writing an implementation of a Binary Search Tree in C, here's a segment of the "insert" procedure:

```
void insert(void *key, struct bst *tree) {
    void n = NULL;
    struct bst **y = &n;
    struct bst **x = &(tree->root);
    struct bst *node = init(key);
    int cmp;

    while (*x != NULL) {
            y = x;
            cmp = <compare  node and x's key>
            if (cmp > 0)
                    x = &((*x)->left);
            else
                    x = &((*x)->right);
    }

    if (y == NULL) /* Empty Tree */
            tree->root = node;
    cmp = <compare node and y's key>

    else if (cmp > 0)
            (*y)->left = node;
    else
            (*y)->right = node;
```

I am using double struct pointers (x and y) so as to make changes to the original tree. Are the double pointers required or would I be able to do so with simple pointers to the tree itself?

EDIT: Got an answer in the comments, I will not be needing pointers.

Comment: You don't need double pointers in the code you've shown.

Comment: @CharlieBurns So, would a simple struct bst *x, *y suffice?

Comment: Yes, and change the rest accordingly.